# call method every 5 minutes in my UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to call a certain method in my UIView code say every 5 minutes - how do I accomplish that?

Comment: `NSTimer`, and `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` to name a couple.. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:inModes:

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use an NSTimer:

Put the following in your viewDidLoad (where 300 is the number of seconds):

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:300.0f
             target:self
         selector:@selector(updateMethod:)
         userInfo:nil
         repeats:YES];
```

And then create your update method:

```
- (void)updateMethod:(NSTimer *)theTimer {
    // Your code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use NSTimer to do this.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html

Specifically,  the 
`timerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:`
class method.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way to do this, in you update method

```
-(void)update{
     //Your update methods here
     [self performSelector:@selector(update) withObject:nil afterDelay:300.0];
}
```